# Analogy between MPNNs and GCNs?

Tags: graph-neural-network

I'm currently trying to understand graph neural networks and got stuck with comparing MPNN and GCN. In my understanding, MPNN is more of a "general framework", while GCN is a specific "instantiation" of that framework. Accordingly, a GCN can be seen as a type of MPNN.

Now, a MPNN always consists of a *message function*, an *aggregation function* and an *update function*.

- The message function is a function from the feature vectors `x_i` and `x_j`, as well as the connecting edge `e_ij` to a new, potentially differently shaped feature vector `m_i`.
- The aggregation function is a function from an arbitrary-sized set of such (latent) feature vectors to a single one (call it `u_i`).
- The update function is a function from a node's own feature vector `x_i` and the aggregated "upstream" features `u_i` to the node's new state `h_i`.

Is that correct so far?

If yes, what would be each of these three functions specifically in the case of a GCN?

In addition, I've read that a GCN cannot handle variable graph structures, i.e. graphs with different number of nodes / edges. I assume this is because the GCN's propagation rule formula has the adjacency matrix in it, which is fixed-size? And then, why / how can a MPNN, instead, deal with different input graphs?

I would be super thankful if somebody could help me sort out these questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I think the problem is that the MPNN paper, introduce both the general framework as well as their own MPNN, which is a little bit cofusing. Generally speaking tho, you only have **message function** and a **vertex update function**. Lastly, you have a **readout function** that aggregates the information on the whole graph using the information on individual nodes.

In the paper the message function and update function of the GCN is rewritten as:

[image]

Lastly, I am not sure what you mean by variable graph structure. But a GCN can handle graphs of different sizes. You can easily see, by looking at the Matrixmulitplications, that the dimensions of adjacency matrix is not important for the multiplication to "work". The only important part, is that you use a good aggregation function in the Readout phase.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only a few follow-up questions in addtion:

(1) The aggregation, in the case of GCNs, is a simple sum, correct?

(2) What potential limitations / disadvantages does a GCN have over an MPNN?

(3) How would you go about incorporating edge-level features as well, in addition to node features? How would the equations for message- and update functions and the matrices' dimensions change accordingly?

Comment: One more question in addition: in that excerpt you posted above, the update function does not take into account a node's own features, does it? So after one step of message passing, a node's own feature vector is "overwritten" entirely by the aggregated states of its neighbors?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can find the derivation with the self-loops in the Message-Passing Paper as well. Here the A is including self-loops. So adding just the Identity matrix to the Adjacency.

[image]

I am note sure, which "aggregation" you are referring to. However, in the GCN the message function computes a weighted mean across all neighbouring nodes. In the original publication the mean is used as a read out function. Generally, speaking the mean is not considered to be a good aggregation function, both on node level as well as the graph level. The choice of aggregation determines which substructures can be differentiated by:

In the paper on Principal Neighborhood aggregation this graphic displays it very well.

[image]